# web services information and how to integrate in the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, service

I am new to web services kind of things, wanted to know what are web services and how we can implement that in our asp.net project.

Searched on many sites but couldn't get the exact solution or a basic example of how to use that.

Could anyone please help.

Comment: If you don't know what web services are, why are you trying to add them to your project? Web services are a solution to a requirement. If you don't have that requirement, then you don't need a web service.

Comment: But the answer to your question, "what are web services?", is that any web site that returns data formatted in a primarily machine-readable, rather than primarily human-readable form can be considered a web service. So if a URL responds with eg JSON or XML, rather than HTML, then it's a web service.

Comment: I haven't read it, but maybe start here...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/webservices/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of implementing webservices. In .Net probably you want to have a look to:

- [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), if you want HTTP Rest webservices
- [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you want to implement SOAP services

In order to take that decision you need to think about the requirements of your services. Who are going to be the clients? Do you need distributed transactions?

Comment: *WCF - if you want to implement SOAP services*, this is a very concise description of a very large framework.

Comment: Actually I want to use it for banking domain.how to use that and where might it can be used possibly for?

Comment: @christiandev yeah, I know. But the question was too broad, so I just tried to cover what I thought it was probably the questioner scenario.

Comment: @Juan, the -1 isn't mine....but I think the question is too broad to even attempt an answer.  I guess you're highlighting the stack that can be used via .NET, so thats a step in the right direction for the OP.

Comment: @christiandev thanks, I just wanted to give the OP somewhere to start, I will leave the answer despise the -1 :)